# Using onto something to convey diligence

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

Context: Someone asked me "*How is the diet plan going*", I thought of replying "*I am onto the diet plan*". I intend to convey that I am eagerly following it today or diligently following it.

Is the sentence "*I am onto the diet plan*" correct or any alternative ways to convey it better?

Comment: You could say "I'm really getting stuck into it!" That means you're following it with energy and enthusiasm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Onto the plan" isn't idiomatic.  I'd assume this was a non-native-speaker error for "on the diet plan".

But this doesn't have any sense of "eagerly following". It just means that I have started following it, and so it doesn't answer the question.

Instead it has the opposite effect, ironically saying that "there is nothing positive to report" and so implying "I am following the rules without enthusiasm or pleasure".

There is an idiom "be into something", but it would require some context

> I'm really getting into it. I'm loving how much more energy I get during the day.

But if you want to simply and clearly indicate that you are eagerly or diligently following the plan  *just use your words*!

> It is going very well. I'm following it diligently.